# Opengraph - clear cache automatically when sharing

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, httpmodule

I have a problem with automatically clearing facebook opengraph cache in .NET application. I want it to work like that:

- User clicks share on facebook with some URL in post content
- Facebook rescrapes data via HttpModule in which I registered event `httpApp.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);` where

  ```
  void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Url != null)
      {
          var urlReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
          var urlDestination = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

          if (urlReferrer.Contains("facebook"))
          {
               var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com");

               var postData = "id=" + urlDestination;
               postData += "&scrape=true";
               var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

               request.Method = "POST";
               request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
               request.ContentLength = data.Length;

               using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
               {
                   stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
               }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Facebook shares updated content

  But it doesn't. I tested my POST request and it works fine when executed in separate project (i check date of last scrape on [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), if it's new i suppose it's ok). 
  When i try to use HttpModule, after publishing my URL - date doesn't change, old value is still there.
   I see some inconsistency, because rescrape takes a few seconds to complete, but after publishing post on facebook old content appears immediately.

EDIT:
I found out, that when link is shared on Facebook and it has been already scraped, then Facebook doesn't event make a request since it's in cache. So solution I mentioned above can't work. It have to be rescraped after changing data - not when it is shared.

Comment: Why would you want to do that _every time_ the URL gets shared? Are you trying to share the same URL, with different data each time? If so, that is a bad idea – if you want to share individual data (maybe user dependent?), then you should use unique, individual URLs for that.

Comment: It's a functionality for a client's demand. Client quite often change site's content via CMS.

Comment: Why not clear the cache when the CMS content changes instead? (rather than at share time? presumably the content will be shared more often than it's changed?)

Comment: I forgot to mention that client also changes site's content by editing database records. The problem is I don't have access to application that is used to update records.